# Is there any particular reason that PHP doesn't do bcadd() whenever + is used?

Tags: php, floating-point, numbers, bc, bcmath

Whenever I'm dealing with numbers in PHP which represent money, I'm forced to use `bcadd()` and the other functions in that "family", instead of simply using the nice symbols such as `+`, `-`, `/` and `*`.

The reason is something about "floats" being inaccurate for some reason. I've many times tried to understand why exactly this is, but I can't make any sense of it.

It would be much nicer to use the symbols instead of the `BC Math` functions.

Why aren't the floats just accurate instead? Or made into "numerics" if "floats" by their nature are inaccurate?

It's not a problem anymore because I know about this, but for most of my life when I'm coded PHP, I had no clue even about the *existence* of those functions, let alone the need to use them.

Comment: There is significant overhead to function calls and the processing of numbers represented as strings. Why not just multiply your values by the required number of decimal places and do integer arithmetic instead?

Comment: @Nick I don't understand what you're suggesting that I do, but it doesn't sound more elegant than the BC Math functions method.

Comment: Treat dollars as integer cents. No issues. Cents as a unit is non-float

Comment: Performance penalty. And PHP doesn't offer operator overloading in general. But there's https://wiki.php.net/rfc/operator_overloading_gmp